# iOS 10 iMessage app content not showing

Tags: messages, ios

Yesterday I updated my iPhone 6 to iOS 10.0.1. Several of my apps, like Pedometer++, Swarm, and Yelp, support iMessage, but instead of showing content I can share, they just show an icon. See the Pedometer++ screenshot below. Swarm, Yelp, etc., appear similarly.

The built-in #images and Music iMessage apps work correctly, as do simple sticker packs.

I've tried power-cycling my phone with no effect. I've also tried disabling and re-enabling the apps in "Manage" with no effect. Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've only seen this when the app hasn't fully downloaded in the background or the internet connection that it relies on is spotty.

Comment: I did the upgrade more than 12 hours ago and the phone was on a good home wifi network for most of the time since then. The apps are fully downloaded and updated to the latest versions.

Comment: Have you tried tapping the icon?

Comment: Tapping the icon has no effect. It's completely static, no animation or anything.

Comment: I have this same issue as well, though for me it affects some apps that have sticker packs (such as Aldo's Adventure), while others with stickers (such as GasBuddy) work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue. What resolved it was deleting each offending app completely and then reinstalling it. Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried this with Yelp and it worked! I'll try the rest of my apps when I have wifi. Thanks!

Comment: ...reinstalling worked immediately for Yelp but not other apps (Pedometer++, OpenTable, and Swarm), but power cycling the phone after reinstalling them fixed everything.